# For Loop Not working in server.r on shiny inside reactive function

Tags: r, string, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am trying to execute a chunk of R code inside a `reactive function`, and in the reactive function, I have a couple of For loop written. It is showing as an unambiguous error in spite the syntax for `For loop is Correct`. I am unable to find whats wrong with the Code.

**Error message in the console after executing the above code shiny application**

[image]

Here in the image as we can see the `^` in the for loop syntax, whats wrong with this I am unable to identify the problem.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But the first error in your log refers to a missing closing `"`. This would cause the R parser to incorrectly interpret all subsequent code. Fix that error first.

Comment: The example code you shared is not properly inside a `reactive()` or anything else. On line 71 of the code you posted you have the closing `}` but no matching `)` so then you have a bunch of code starting on line 72 that shiny expects to be separated by commas when in reality you've simply not properly enclosed.

Comment: @MrFlick i agree with you , if their would have been error with missing `"` then i there would have some flag of error , neither it is showing that hint .

Comment: @Mark .  for (i2 in 1:length(z)){
    # s[[i2]] <- as.li2st(z[[i2]][5])}
    s[[i2]] <- as.list(paste(z[[i2]][5],z[[i2]][6]))} are talking about this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the file to UTF 8 encoding format.

Here is the instruction to solve the above problem

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html